# delete last accordion with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can add an accordian with jQuery. But now I want also to delete the last selected accordian. I have it like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="span12" id="delete-contact">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#">Klik hier om contactpersoon te verwijderen</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#delete-contact p a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.panel').get(0).remove();
});
```

But this doesn't work

This is the html:

```
 <div class="span12" id="add-contact">
          <p style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="#">Klik hier om nog een contactpersoon toe te voegen</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span12" id="delete-contact">
          <p style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="#">Klik hier om contactpersoon te verwijderen</a>
          </p>
        </div>
```

And this is for add and delete accordian:

```
// Add extra contact clicked?
                                $('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields
                                    html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();

                        // Get number of tabs in the accordion
                        var index = $('#accordion h3').length;



                    if(index == 0 )
{
                         alert($('#accordion h3').length);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canorder_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canseestock_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canseeorders_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canseeprice_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canseecredit_0').prop('checked', true);
                        $('#contactpersonen_canseepickup_0').prop('checked', true);

}               


                                    // Remove the values
                                    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
                  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

                        // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
                        html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            me = $(this);
                            attr = me.attr('id');
                            number = attr.split('_')[2];
                            newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
                            newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
                            me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
                        });                  

                                    // Insert it at the end
                        $('#accordion').append(html);
                        $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

                        // Set last tab to active
                        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: index });

                                    // Cancel the click
                                    return false;
                                });


                            $('#delete-contact p a').click(function(event)
                                {
                                        event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.panel').eq(0).remove();
          //$("#accordion).accordion("destroy");    // Removes the accordion bits
         //$("#accordion").empty();  



                                    });
```

If I do this:

```
$('#delete-contact p a').click(function(event)
                                {
                                        event.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parents('.panel').eq(0).remove();
         // $("#accordion).accordion("destroy");    // Removes the accordion bits
         $("#accordion").empty();      


                                    });
```

Then all the accordians will be deleted. So for example I have two accordians and the last one - two have to be deleted. But now both will be deleted.

I try it like this:

```
$('#delete-contact p a').click(function(event)
                                {
                                        event.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parents('.panel').eq(0).remove();
        // $("#accordion).accordion("destroy");    // Removes the accordion bits
         $("#accordion").empty({ active: index });
```

But now neither accordian will be deleted

```
            });
```

Comment: `get(0)` gets the native DOM node, which in some modern browsers would have a `remove()` method, but you probably wanted the jQuery object, and for that you'd use `eq(0)` instead.

Comment: So I changed that. What's next??

Answer (score 0):

For page redirect problem on link click, try this :

```
<a href="#">Klik hier om nog een contactpersoon toe te voegen</a>
```

replace href attributes with "javascript:void(0)" that will prevent page loading.

For ex. :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Klik hier om nog een contactpersoon toe te voegen</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I solved that. I made update in the post